# How to accept data only from our site when we post data to ashx?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Suppose we are doing ajax call to post data to an aashx, how can we make sure that data is posted from only our site?

Comment: You can't. You are asking for a mechanism to authenticate the calling software. No such mechanism exists. If there are no big security or licensing concerns, you could try using the referrer header.

Comment: Just to make sure: when you say "posted from our site", do you mean from the browser or from the server? I am assuming the browser.

Comment: Read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy